# Should iOS app's plist be compressed for optimization purposes?

Tags: ios, serialization

The app I have under development is utilizing a lot of plist that's taking up a lot of space.  I am considering zipping up the plist files.  At runtime, the app will unzip them into NSData and deserialize them into NSDictionary using NSPropertyListSerialization for eventual use.

Is there anything risky about this approach? Or is it useless if Property List Output Encoding is set to binary.

Comment: And what is the biggest size of one of your .plist file?

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting to the point where you're considering zipping up property lists to save on space, I think it's time to move to a different format.  Property lists are good for storing a few defaults or some settings, but they're not a replacement for a database.

My recommendation would be to look at moving this data into a Core Data database.  If you are trying to embed large digital files as elements in the property list, look at storing those as separate resources in your application bundle or in your application's /Documents directory.

Core Data will allow you to lazy-load items as you need them, saving on load times and memory, and its SQLite base will provide for fast read / write times.

Comment: I have chosen plist so it's easier for us to edit/exchange data with other people.  The data is prepared by many folks so I need to have the ability to use simple tools to access/modify the data.  That's why I went with the plist route.  The data are mostly read-only and I do not perform searches on them.

Answer (score 0):

If your project settings are properly set up (that is, the *Property List Output Encoding* you mentioned is set to binary in the active *target*'s settings), all of the .plist files will be converted to binary form. Look inside the bundle of your build product and check what the sizes of files are.

**Update:**

Further investigation shows that if you add a directory containing your plist files as a *Folder Reference*, Xcode will not look inside it, it will simply copy its contents into the produced bundle. Therefore, you should convert plists yourself using **plutil**.

A possible way do automate the task is to add a Build Script phase to your target in Xcode and make it recursively copy all the files from the directory `A` to the directory `B` converting all the files that end in *.plist*. Then add `B` to your target as a reference instead of `A` and you're good to go.

You could also simply create a new directory for binary plists and add them to your target instead of ordinary XML plists.

Here's how the script might look. Supposing all of your plists are stored in a directory named `dir` (or any of its subdirectories) and it is located at path `/path/to/dir`. To convert them all into directory `/path/to/B` one could write the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

find "/path/to/dir" -iname '*.plist' | xargs -L 1 -J % cp % "/path/to/B"
find "/path/to/B" -iname '*.plist' | xargs -L 1 plutil -convert binary1
```

Comment: I looked inside the app bundle, they are still in xml format.  And the size is exactly the same as before it was packaged into app.

Comment: If you are looking inside the app bundle using the Finder, it will display the .plist as XML. I just look at Info.plist on one of my app from Terminal.app and it's in binary format. `cat Info.plist` and let me know what you get.  Then use `plutil -convert xml1 Info.plist` and `cat` the output again.

Comment: Info.plist is binary, so is another custom plist I created for the app located at the same level as Info.plist.  But all the other plist files inside a folder is not binary.  Could the location of the plist file matter?

Comment: Thanks Alexei.  I will verify your solution.